# JavaScript - Selenium Webdriver. How to check if element is visible

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

Im using Selenium to open a page. After I open the page, I want to click a some sort of refresh button. When I click it, Im getting this error:

> ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

This is the code I use to click the button:

`driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();`

My guess is that the button goes not visible whenever it is pushed. And that maybe it starts off not visible as well. Cause it doesnt do a full page refresh.

Any way for selenium to check if something is visible, and maybe wait until it is?

Edit:
As it turns out, there are multiple buttons with the same ID. And the button I am trying to reach are way down. I tried to find the button with `By.xpath`, but I still couldnt find it. The way I did it, was to search for button by id, like this `//button[contains(@id, 'abc')][1]`. (Different number of course).

Selenium could not find the element, but I could find it with Chrome developer tools. Any suggestions?

Comment: If after you try everything and still fail.
Please note. Sometimes you browser starts up too small the button is visible, but it is outside of the visible area of the window. So web driver cannot click it.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the error that its not visible, after it finds the element. 

`driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id)), 3000, '\nCannot find element by  id: ' + _id);`

`driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();`

Comment: try maximize the window before loading up the page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried maximizing the window, right after I started the driver, with this command: `driver.manage().window().maximize();`. Its before I even open the page, so its a few clicks before the button is visible. But Im still getting the same error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide your html page?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant give you the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: 1** You can try using this code in a syso,

```
System.out.println("getting Page Source "+driver.getPageSource());
```

This method will return the entire page `Source` and you can check whether your button exists in the source or not. You can place the above code at several points in your function and check until you find the button in the source.

**Solution: 2** In case your button does not exist in the source you will have to check and see whether the button is getting loaded in an iframe and if so you can use the following code and switch to the iframe and and then try finding the button,

```
driver.switchTo.frame(frameName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your sollutions later today. Im using JavaScript, and not Java. And Im really new to JS. Do you also know how to do it in JS?

Comment: You are writing the Selenium code in javascript?if so you can use an alert instead or you can debug in F12 and check .

Comment: Using alert:
alert("getting Page Source "+driver.getPageSource());
Using F12:

Comment: Do you know how to use F12?in IE and Google Chrome F12 is available.

Comment: Okay I will try reading out the entire source code, and see if I can find the button there. Yes I know how to use F12. Im using Chrome. The weird thing is that i am using the exact same code to find the button with xpath in Chrome developer tools, as Selenium is using to find the button. I can find the button. Selenium can not.

Comment: Sometimes even though the button can be seen in your F12 ,it may be present in your source only after some condition has been satisfied.Once you get the source you can try searching with the help of the id used.Is there any chance that the element you are searching for appears only on a condition like c:if or something like that?

Comment: Yes maybe. Do you have a good function to make selenium wait for x amount of seconds?

Comment: This is the code i have been using in java,i guess the functionality must be the same,
WebElement element=driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id)), 3000);

Comment: In Java it is like this,
WebElement element=(new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(id))));
there must be the equivalent code in js as well.(20 being the number of seconds)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could use Explicit wait to check when the element/button is clickable.
Try doing this
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(id))

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a wait function, that waits for the driver to find the element.
`driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id)), 3000, '\nCannot find element by id: ' + id);`